# Can't pass arguments to a script from a list

Tags: python, ipython, argparse

I'm trying to run a python script for each `png` file in a folder. `run.py` takes a png file by `--path_to_load` arg, and returns processed png file into `path_to_save` arg. I managed to get png files into `pngfiles` list and setup the for loop as below:

```
import glob
import os
import cv2

pngfiles = []

for pngfile in glob.glob('selected_faces/**/*.png', recursive=True):
    pngfiles.append(pngfile) #returns 'selected_faces\pngfilename.ext' to a list

print (pngfiles[:2])

#['selected_faces\\S005_001_00000001.png', 
#'selected_faces\\S005_001_00000011.png']    

    for file in pngfiles:
        filename = file.split('\\')[1] 
        print(filename)
        #S005_001_00000001.png
        #returns correct first file name    
        save_path = os.path.join('aligned_faces',filename) #returns save path
        print(save_path)
        #aligned_faces\S005_001_00000001.png
        #returns correct save path
        print(file)
        #selected_faces\S005_001_00000001.png
        #returns correct load path
        %run run.py --mode 1 --path_to_load=file --path_to_save=save_path
```

Running the code returns an OpenCV assertion error !_src_empty() probably due to input file cant' be read.

```
error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

But running the code out of the loop lets says just for a single file, it works as intended:

```
%run run.py --mode 1 --path_to_load="selected_faces\image1.png" --path_to_save="aligned_faces\image1.png"
```

I checked out that both `file` and `save_path` are strings and seems there are no problems with that. Or maybe I'm missing something obviously.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you running a python file from another python file? In the loop where you are iterating through all the pngfiles, you can read the image, and also save it in some other folder (in the same script, without using `run.py` ).

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the correct `filename`? If `file = 'selected_faces\\subdir\\image.png'` then `filename = file.split('\\')[1]` will return `subdir`. Shouldn't it be `filename = file.split('\\')[-1]` or better `import ntpath` and `filename = ntpath.basename(file)`?

Comment: `%run` isn't valid Python; that's an iPython/Jupyter magic command.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that the script is not receiving the input file correctly. Since they are relative paths, I would suggest starting by checking each value of `file` in the loop and even the current path `os.getcwd ()`.

Comment: Can you add a `print` to verify file names that it receives? We are guessing from the `%run` that this is an `ipython` session.

Comment: @hpaulj I've printed various variables and commented them out.

Comment: You need to check the `run.py` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you are using `%run` right:

```
In [406]: for x in ['one','tow','three']: 
     ...:     %run echo.py -x x 
     ...:                                                                                              
['echo.py', '-x', 'x']
['echo.py', '-x', 'x']
['echo.py', '-x', 'x']
In [407]: for x in ['one','tow','three']: 
     ...:     %run echo.py -x $x 
     ...:                                                                                              
['echo.py', '-x', 'one']
['echo.py', '-x', 'tow']
['echo.py', '-x', 'three']
```

Comment: You nailed it boss. Thanks.